# Code for buy one get one free adds free products for all products in cart

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2

I have modified this code below to add a buy one get one free for all products of a category id 525 but when product of this category is added, it gives one free product for all products in cart. How do I filter this code so that it gives one free if only a product from category 525 is added. Thanks

```
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $Qty1 = $item->getQty();
    if(($Qty1=>1) && ($rule->getGiftSku()=='TBFTIGI009')){


                  $f1product = $item->getProduct();
                  $f1_productsku =$f1product->getSku();
                   //$rule->setGiftSku($f1_productsku);
                  $freeItem1 = static::_getFreeQuoteItem($quote, $f1_productsku, $item->getStoreId(), (int)$rule->getDiscountAmount());

                  $quote->addItem($freeItem1);
                  $freeItem1->setApplyingRule($rule);
                  $rule->setIsApplied(true);           }
    }
    ////

    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $freeItem */
    $freeItem = static::_getFreeQuoteItem($quote, $rule->getGiftSku(), $item->getStoreId(), (int)$rule->getDiscountAmount());
    if ($freeItem && $rule->getGiftSku()!='TBFTIGI009')
    {
        $quote->addItem($freeItem);
        $freeItem->setApplyingRule($rule);
        $rule->setIsApplied(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Mage::log(
            sprintf(
                'C4B_Freeproduct: Gift product not saleable. Rule ID: %d, Gift SKU: %s, Store ID: %d',
                $rule->getId(), $rule->getGiftSku(), $quote->getStoreId()
            ), Zend_Log::ERR
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition before adding free item to cart like this -

```
if (in_array("525", $f1product ->getCategoryIds())) {
             $freeItem1 = static::_getFreeQuoteItem($quote, $f1_productsku, $item->getStoreId(), (int)$rule->getDiscountAmount());

              $quote->addItem($freeItem1);
              $freeItem1->setApplyingRule($rule);
              $rule->setIsApplied(true);
}
```